# How to calculate spatial averag for certain area in abinary file using R?

Tags: r, binary

I have been searching for long time to find out how we can calculate a spatial average by R.However,i failed to find something.I have a binary file has 720 columns and 360 rows,float of air temperature. and I want first to calculate the spatial average over the whole area and to calculate the spatial average over an area of (500-600 colu and 200-250rows) and then extract the area.

```
t<- file("C:annual_Prc2000_without999_1.img","rb")
 e=readBin(t, double(), size=4,n=720*360, signed=TRUE)
```

from answer 1 :

```
             mean(e)
                I got 
                NaN
```

from answer 2:i got

```
              spat_mean = apply(e, c(2,1), mean)
            Error in apply(e, c(2, 1), mean) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

let me explain it:
assume

```
       m <- matrix(rnorm(10000),4,4)
         > m
            [,1]       [,2]         [,3]       [,4]
   [1,]  0.7930132  2.1973895  0.063493345 -0.5484056
   [2,]  0.5222513  0.4331308 -0.002393336  0.1725495
   [3,]  1.7462222 -1.5701996 -2.276781240  0.5628531
   [4,] -1.2713361 -0.9349057  0.757412225  1.5118180
        > mean(m)
      [1] 0.134757
        now I want this:
          [,1]       [,2]         [,3]       [,4]
   [1,] 0.134757   0.134757     0.134757    0.134757
   [2,]  0.134757   0.134757     0.134757   0.134757
    [3,]  0.134757   0.134757       0.134757   0.134757
    [4,] 0.134757    0.134757     0.134757     0.134757
```

I did this manually but i want to do it thru R

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a regular spatial grid, you probably want something like this:

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rnorm(10000),100,100)

#calculate mean of all values
mean(m)

#calculate mean of region 1:10 * 1:10
mean(m[1:10,1:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment to the other answer I gather that you want to calculate the mean value per x,y pair. For this you can use `apply`. Assuming you have a multi-dimensional array with x,y,time dimensions, getting the mean per x,y pair is done like this:

```
spat_mean = apply(multi_dim_array, c(1,2), mean)
```

`spat_mean` is now a 2d array with x,y dimensions, giving the spatial mean.

Comment: The error you have with my code is caused by the fact that your numbers are in a 1d vector. Use `dim` to assign the appropriate dimensions.